# Group Isomorphism - Associativity - Change of Operator

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Sorry about the title - I wasn't sure about how to be more specific.

This is a homework problem, where I've only been able to write down (ii).

**Let (S,*) be a binary system. Define the opposite operation *' to * by a*'b=b*a.**

- (i) Prove that if * is associative, then so is *'.
- (ii) Give an example where (S, *) and (S, *') are not isomorphic. <--- Done.
- (iii) Prove that if (S,*) is a group, then (S, *') and (S, *) are isomorphic.

Comment: What are the properties of a group? What is a group isomorphism?

Comment: Note that commutativity is not a defining property of a group, rather it is an additional property a group can have.

Comment: Please note the obvious misprint, you surely mean $a *' b = b * a$.

Comment: @ErikG.: Part (iii) is true whether $(S,*)$ is abelian or not (but if it's not abelian, then the identity map is not an isomorphism).

Comment: @Brad I made no comment about the relevance of commutativity. What I said was it is not a basic property of a group.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti - thx for that correction.

Comment: @ErikG., thx for your comments - I've since then created the proof.

Comment: @JoshuaBunce good luck, hopefully you keep asking (good) questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is a homework problem, here are some hints.

For (i), evaluate $(a*'b)*'c$ and $a*'(b*'c)$, keeping in mind that $*$ is associative, and show that they are equal. Then $*'$ is associative.

For (iii), try verifying that $f\colon (S,*)\to (S,*'):x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is a group isomorphism.